# Simple blackjack game; function to "stand" will only print "you win" for all conditions met

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I am programing a simple blackjack game but my function to "stand" will only print "you win" for all conditions met.

```
function stand(){
    if(gethandvalue(playerhand) < dealerhand ){
        document.getElementById("game-status").innerHTML = "you lose";
    }
    if(gethandvalue(playerhand) === dealerhand){
        document.getElementById("game-status").innerHTML =" its a tie";
    }
    else(gethandvalue(playerhand) > dealerhand)
        document.getElementById("game-status").innerHTML ="you win!";
        youwinsound.play();
    }
```

When the dealer's hand gets higher than the player's hand the code still prints out "you win".

Comment: Maybe the value of `dealerhand` is not what you expect it to be at that point in the code. Why does it use the function `gethandvalue()` for the player's hand but not for the dealer's hand? Oh, and the statements for the `else` should be in `{ }`.

Comment: Shouldn't the `else` be `else if`? Plus you have a missing `{` and `}` around the last two-line block.

Comment: can you post the gethandvalue and getdealerhandvalue function?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `if`s are a bit muddled. If the first two cases have been eliminated, then the third case is what is left, so you don't need to actually test for it.

If you put the message into a variable, it keeps things tidy for when you set the text: e.g. if you changed the id of the element showing the message, you'd only have to change it in one place.

I assume that `playerhand` and `dealerhand` are two instances of some `hand` entity, so to get the value you just need to call the same function for each.

Variable names can be used to help show what is being done, something like this:

```
function stand() {
    var gameStatusMessage;
    var playerHandValue = gethandvalue(playerhand);
    var dealerHandValue = gethandvalue(dealerhand);

    if (playerHandValue < dealerHandValue) {
        gameStatusMessage = "you lose";
    }
    else if (playerHandValue === dealerHandValue) {
        gameStatusMessage = "it's a tie";
    } 
    else { /* last case: playerHandValue > dealerHandValue) */
        gameStatusMessage = "you win!";
        youwinsound.play();
    }

    document.getElementById("game-status").innerHTML = gameStatusMessage;

}
```